# Resetting Timer issues IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, timer, nstimer

I'm working on a `buzzer app for IOS`. When you `click the buzzer`, it buzzes, `30 seconds` pops up, and counts down until `after 1` and then buzzes and disappears. If, during the course of the `30-second countdown`, someone wants to reset the buzzer (so that the timer goes off and disappears), they will just click the `buzzer again`.

I have three questions:
**1. How do you start the app with the UILabel invisible and then shows up upon the first click?**
**2. How do you reset the buzzer by clicking it during the 30 second countdown?**
**3. Will reseting the buzzer fix the problem of the timer going down extremely quick when clicked multiple times?**

viewcontrol.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UILabel *seconds;
    NSTimer *timer;
    int MainInt;
    SystemSoundID buzzer;

}


- (IBAction)start:(id)sender;
- (void)countdown;

@end
```

ViewController.m
    #import "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {
   seconds.hidden = NO;
   MainInt = 30;
   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(buzzer);

}


-(void)countdown {
    MainInt -= 1;
    seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", MainInt];
    if (MainInt < 1) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
        seconds.hidden = YES;
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(buzzer);
        }


}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Buzz" ofType:@"wav"]];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &buzzer);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) hiding the label on startup

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

   [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //hide the label initially
    [seconds setHidden:YES];

    /// other code
```

then call `[seconds setHidden:NO];` in start method

2) reset buzzer

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {
   seconds.hidden = NO;
   MainInt = 30;

   if(timer != nil)
   {
      //timer exist..stop previous timer first.
     [timer invalidate];
   }

   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(buzzer);

}
```

Comment: Great! This helps a lot. On question 2, by "reset" I mean I want it to reset to the default of not being on. Basically, I want it to cancel the buzzer so that no countdown is going. How do I do that?

Also, after the buzzer has accomplished one cycle, when it is clicked again the numbering goes like this: "0, 29, 28, 27."

How do I fix that?

Comment: Found the answer. I created an if statement that determined if the timer was running. If so, I invalidated the timer, set it to nil, hid the seconds, reset the main int, and set the seconds (still hidden) to 30 seconds.

'-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {
    if (timer != nil) {
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
        seconds.hidden = YES;
        MainInt = 30;
        seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"30"];
        } else {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(buzzer);
        [self performSelector:@selector(buzzerDelay) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.85];
    }
}'

Answer (score 0):

1) For the label becoming visible on a delay, initialize the label (in code or in IB) with `seconds.alpha = 0.0`.  Then to make it visible...

```
NSTimeInterval delayUntilLabelIsVisible = 3.0;  // 3 seconds
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                      delay:delayUntilLabelIsVisible
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn
                 animations:^{seconds.alpha = 1.0;}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

2,3) Your second and third questions can be solved with a line of code in the start method...

```
-(IBAction)start:(id)sender {

   seconds.hidden = NO;
   MainInt = 30;

   // cancel the old timer before creating a new one
   // (otherwise many timers will run at once, calling the buzzer method too often)
   [timer invalidate];

   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countdown) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(buzzer);
}
```